# I am using try catch but it's still throwing an error in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Here's the page constructor code

```
public DebitNoteCreation(int transactionID) :
        this()
    {
        try
        {
            InsertDebitNote dn = new InsertDebitNote();
            dn.Load(transactionID);
            this.DataContext = dn;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Some of the entries for this transaction are empty so kindly complete them", "Error");
        }
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("DisplayTransaction.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

Error Message

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I am able to see the message box but after i click the ok button, it throws the above written error.

Comment: What is the stack trace (with line numbers) of the this exception?

Comment: please post the exact call stack

Comment: As a side note, it is very bad practice to catch general exceptions like that.

Comment: The error is happening because of an empty datetime. I am deliberately doing this. What i want is to navigate to other page when such situation arises. Mark method sounds fine. Will check on that

Comment: "The error is happening because of an empty datetime. I am deliberately doing this." - then **check** for the empty datetime. Don't just assume that any `Exception` means it was this specific scenario. There are ***any number*** of crazy things that can happen ***at any time***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the error happens *after* you click OK, I *expect* that `this.NavigationService` is `null`, due to the failing constructor.

Also, you shouldn't assume that `Exception` means "Some of the entries for this transaction are empty so kindly complete them", and allowing a constructor to succeed when it has clearly failed to fully initialize an object is very dangerous.

In fact, **only** the UI should be doing message-boxes *anyway*. I would rewrite such that it throws a known exception after checking the transactions (i.e. the scenario you expect to be a problem). Let the UI catch that exception and do the message box there.

Comment: Your method sounds the right approach. Will try to see how can i do that. Also, i know why the error is thrown, its because of an empty DateTime field. What i wanted is that when this error is thrown, the page should navigate to other page where he can complete the transaction

Comment: @Pankaj  "i know why the error is thrown" let me state: **no, you don't**. You know ***one single*** reason that an `Exception` is thrown. It is ***invalid*** to then assume that *any* `Exception` means this. It could be that the data-context is disposed? the database was unavailable? out-of-memory? thread-abort? stack-overflow? I see random things ***every day***, that are completely outside anyone's ability to safely predict.

Comment: **I have made changes to the page constructor code and its like this now.** 
`InsertDebitNote dn = new InsertDebitNote(); loadMessage = dn.Load(transactionID); if (loadMessage == true) { this.DataContext = dn; } else { this.DataContext = null; }` 

**I am confused as to how can i navigate the page ?? Since when i put the navigation code in constructor it throws the Null Reference**

Comment: @Pankaj I can't see the navigation code - can you point it out? But a constructor is not really a great place for navigation logic...

Comment: @Mark Now, i am not playing with the page constructor as if the transaction fails to load there is no need for the page. Therefore, i am checking for the transaction load on previous page itself; if it loads then the object will be passed or an error message will be displayed if the FormatException occurs.

Answer (score 1):

If the exception is thrown so that the messagebox is shown, that suggests something went wrong... and you won't have assigned anything to `this.DataContext`. That could well cause follow-on errors.

Look at the stack trace of the `NullReferenceException` to see *exactly* what's throwing it, but basically you're trying to keep going with an incompletely-initialized object, which is rarely a good idea.

(Note that you should probably catch a more specific exception, and you should definitely log it rather than just showing a message box and then ignoring it.)

If you *have* to keep going, set the context to an empty note or something like that. I suspect you don't actually want to show the page in that case though. You may want to consider loading the transaction *before* constructing the page, to make things a bit cleaner.

Comment: Well, i know why the error is thrown, its because of an empty DateTime field. What i wanted is that when this error is thrown, the page should navigate to other page where he can complete the transaction

Comment: @Pankaj: Then you should try to load the transaction *before* trying to display the page at all. Then you can display whatever page is most appropriate - the success case one, or the failure one - based on whether the transaction load worked.

Comment: @Pankaj - see the error I added under my reply; short version: "no, you don't"

Comment: @Jon : Where i should put the navigation code, Since when i put the navigation code in constructor it throws the Null Reference. Is there any event that occurs after consturctor in which i can safely place the navigation code??

Comment: @Pankaj: You ought to put the code to load this *before* you start constructing another page IMO. If you can't load the transaction, you don't need the page, do you? The results of loading the transaction guide which page you want to display.

Comment: @Jon : Thanks buddy for clearing the air. You are absolutely correct that i don't need the page when transaction cannot load. It was stupid of me not to think that way. Once again thanks